# Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs

Tags: emacs, ssh, sudo, tramp

I want to open a file inside Emacs which is located on a remote server, with sudo powers on the server. I can open local files with sudo via Tramp like this:

```
C-x C-f /sudo::/home/user/file
```

But I want to use sudo on the server:

```
C-x C-f /sudo::user@server/home/user/file
```

But this gives me sudo powers on my local machine, it asks for my sudo password on the local machine. Is there a way to use sudo on the server?

BTW: Emacs is not installed on the server

Comment: can't you command as root directly on the server?

Comment: I have a user with sudo privileges, but not the root password.

Answer (score 221, accepted):

As of Emacs 24.3, an analog of the old `multi:` syntax has been layered on top of the modern `tramp-default-proxies-alist` approach, meaning that you can once again perform multi-hops without any prior configuration. For details, see:

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(tramp)Ad-hoc multi-hops` <kbd>RET</kbd>

With the new syntax, each 'hop' is separated by `|`. The example in the manual is:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `/ssh:bird@bastion|ssh:you@remotehost:/path` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Which connects firstly as `bird@bastion`, and from there to `you@remotehost:/path`

### /su: or /sudo: on remote hosts

You can also use this syntax to sudo/su to root (or of course any other user) on a remote host:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:remotehost:/path/to/file` <kbd>RET</kbd>

**Important**: be sure to specify the hostname explicitly: `sudo:remotehost:` rather than `sudo::` (see below).

As this still uses the proxy mechanism underneath, `tramp-default-proxies-alist` should now include the value `("remotehost" "root" "/ssh:you@remotehost:")`

Meaning that the proxy `/ssh:you@remotehost:` is going to be used whenever you request a file as `root@remotehost`.

`root` is the default user for these methods, but you can of course also change to a non-root user with:

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:them@remotehost:/path/to/file` <kbd>RET</kbd>

### Always specify the remote hostname explicitly

You are probably used to using `sudo::` or `su::` and omitting the hostname. If you are *staying* on the localhost then this is still fine, but if you are hopping to a remote server then you *must* specify the hostname for every hop -- even if it is the same as for the previous hop. Always use `sudo:hostname:` or `su:hostname:` with remote hosts.

The trap here is that `sudo::` *does* actually appear to work -- *however* when you do that the HOST for the dynamic proxy entry will be the hostname you *originated* from rather than the host you connected to. This will not only look confusing (as the wrong host will be displayed in the file paths), but it will also mean that any subsequent attempt to use `sudo::` on your localhost will instead be proxied to the remote server! (and the proxy would also presumably be clobbered if you did the same thing on a second server, causing further issues).

In short, don't use `::` when you multi-hop!

### Emacs 27+

Starting from Emacs 27.1 (or Tramp 2.4.2, if using the GNU ELPA package) the `::` case works intuitively, such that `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo::` will re-use `remotehost` rather than your own local host, and so you won't end up with a bad proxy entry.

In addition, the likes of `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:localhost:` are detected and flagged as user errors.

If you are liable to use a mixture of Emacs versions including versions earlier than 27 (or you are advising someone else who may be using an older version), then it would be safest to continue to treat `::` as unsafe when multi-hopping, to avoid potential mishap.  (I.e. specifying the correct remote host explicitly will remain the safest approach if the Tramp version is unknown.)

Comment: and now added to wikemacs as well http://wikemacs.org/index.php/TRAMP. Thanks phils, it works great.

Comment: I just found this answer, and it works great...except that I have hostname shorthand defined in an .ssh/config file. When I type `/sudo:hostname:/etc/hosts`, I get what you would expect, but when I type `/sudo:abbrev:/etc/hosts`, I get the message "Host abbrev looks like a remote host, sudo can only use the local host". Is this fixable?

Comment: rogerl: I also have `.ssh/config` entries, and I don't have any problems using `/ssh:abbrev|sudo:abbrev:/etc/hosts` for my hostname abbreviations. It looks like you're not hopping to the host first.

Comment: @phils Perhaps I should post this as a new question. However: my config file looks like
Host r
     User rlipsett
     Hostname odlinux
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id-rsa.pub
and my `tramp-default-proxies-alist` appears to be correct. Yet the behavior I described above persists. Is my config file somehow wrong?

Comment: It's still not clear to me whether you are *actually* trying to use `/sudo:abbrev:/etc/hosts` as you put in your previous comment (which is wrong, as mentioned), or if you're using the correct `/ssh:abbrev|sudo:abbrev:/etc/hosts`. Your ssh config file is presumably fine, as you can evidentially use it otherwise.

Comment: If you *do* have the correct `tramp-default-proxies-alist` config already in place, then you can likely use `/sudo:root@abbrev:/etc/hosts` as (slight) shorthand; but I'd suggest using the longer form in general.

Comment: @phils The only reason I was trying that shorthand syntax at all was because of your answer [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/21752/setting-up-shortcut-using-tramp-default-proxies-alist). It's really unfortunate that there is no decent shorthand, since I use emacs to manage files on a remote server regularly.

Comment: Ah, I see. That wasn't *my* answer, though -- and I didn't spot the issue when I was commenting on it, because I only ever manually type the paths using the longer syntax. I'll grant you that it's awfully odd that Michael Albinus would have written something incorrect about tramp, but it rather seems that way. You should follow up that answer and query it with him.

Comment: @phils root ssh login has to be enabled for though correct?

Comment: @Startec, I wouldn't have thought so, but if you've tested and found that to be the case then I can't nay-say it.

Comment: @phils could you give just a little bit of explanation as to what the `|` does? For instance, at the end of it, am I logged in as `user` or `root`? I it as though I `ssh`'d as the root user?  Currently this is not working as this "times out".

Comment: @phils this does not work. Emacs just hangs forever.  It asks me for the password for the root user, and here is the error log:

https://pastebin.com/M20ezpgi

Comment: I can't really help, sorry. I can see that "Tramp: Waiting for prompts from remote shell...failed" has timed out after password entry, but the reason is not clear to me. I trust you do have sudo access in the first place? Note that the password you're asked for is commonly the original user's password, not the root user's password (although it may vary between systems and configs), in which case the user needs to have been granted permission to use sudo. I suggest that you confirm your sudo access outside of Emacs, if you have not done so already.

Comment: @phils [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8363532/3291506) was my issue / solution!

Comment: Quick update -- As of Emacs 27, the `::` case will work the way you want it to, such that `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo::` will re-use `remotehost` rather than your own local hostname, so you won't end up with a bad proxy entry.  In addition, the likes of `/ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:localhost:` are detected and flagged as user errors.  (Of course, if you are liable to use a mixture of Emacs versions, you should continue to treat `::` as unsafe when multi-hopping in general, to avoid potential mishap.)

Comment: How might I configure trap to use `dzdo`  instead of `sudo`?

https://docs.centrify.com/Content/aud-events/dzdo.htm

Comment: @willwillis I've never heard of that one, but start at `C-h v tramp-methods` and look at the definitions for similar methods `sudo`, `su`, `ksu`, `doas`, `sg`.  See also `C-h i g (tramp)Inline methods`.  From there you may or may not need to dig deeper into how these are handled in the code, but that should provide a starting point.

Answer (score 21):

**Update**: Although this answer solved the original problem, it was written for emacs 20 or 21. For emacs 24, I recommend you use [phils's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16408592/172599) because it offers more explanation and is up to date.

---

I think [multi-hop filenames](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Multi_002dhops) in tramp is what you're looking for.

The first hop would be ssh and the second would be sudo.

---

Update: Recent versions of emacs support multiple hops using proxies:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist ("my-sudo-alias" nil "/ssh:user@ssh-host"))
```

Then invoke by opening:

```
/sudo:my-sudo-alias:file-on-ssh-host
```

Comment: This seems like the solution, but I get: 
"multi method is no longer supported"
Can you point me to an updated manual?

Comment: M-x info, C-s tramp :) You may need to define a fake host as the target of your sudo and add it to tramp-default-proxy-alist.

Comment: I couldn't get it running in my configuration (error 255?), but the following line in .emacs works:
(set-default 'tramp-default-proxies-alist (quote (("my-sudo-alias" nil "/ssh:user@ssh-host:"))))

Comment: The updated answer doesn't define "recent", has invalid elisp, and doesn't work even when you correct it.  I'm on a stable version of emacs released over a year after the updated answer.

Comment: I had to use `tramp-default-proxies-alist` for this; but when I try to visit a file `sudo:my-sudo-alias:/etc/anything` Emacs complains about "Method `scpc' is not supported for multi-hops.". Any ideas?

Comment: The *real* answer as of 2014/24.3 is the following answer, using "ad-hoc multi-hops"

Answer (score 7):

I had some troubles with the selected answer.  However, it worked when I added this line to .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist '(".*" "\\`root\\'" "/ssh:%h:"))
```

And then executed the following:

`/sudo:ssh-host:file-on-ssh-host`

It was slightly confusing because at one point I was prompted for the "root" password, but entering my user's password granted me access.  It also universally works on all hosts on the network.  Also, I can still do this to not be root:

`/ssh:ssh-host:file-on-ssh-host`

Comment: This was not working for me. It looks that in Ubuntu, at least with version 23.2.1 of Emacs and version 2.1.18-23.2 of tramp this does not work. 
This works, though: http://info.solomonson.com/content/doing-sudo-remote-server-emacs-opensave-file

Comment: (set-default 'tramp-default-proxies-alist (quote ((".*" "\\`root\\'" "/ssh:%h:"))))

Comment: I am not able to get either of the solutions above to work (add-to-list or set-default). The first causes Emacs to choke on startup and the second gives me "Host `abc.xyz.com' looks like a remote host, `sudo' can only use the local host" as soon as I enter the second colon in "/sudo:abc.xyz.com:". Ideas? Emacs 23.1.1 on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

From the [tramp multi-hops configuration webpage](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Multi_002dhops.html)

```
 (add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
                   '(nil "\\`root\\'" "/ssh:%h:"))
      (add-to-list 'tramp-default-proxies-alist
                   '((regexp-quote (system-name)) nil nil))
```

Then any

```
C-x C-f /sudo:remote-host:/file
```

will open file using *sudo* after logged with the same username of the user running emacs but on the remote machine.

Answer (score -13):

You have to ssh into the server first, then you have to run emacs locally.

Or you can use NFS with no_root_squash, or you can try with emacs server/client, although I have no idea of what may happen (do not use emacs myself)

Comment: I tried, but I cannot access files as root with sshfs, when mounting it as regular user. I guess it is a setup problem.

Comment: As Hassan noted, no_root_squash should be used with care.

Comment: -1 for not answering the question. -1 for suggesting NFS instead of SSH. -1 for suggesting no_root_squash. -1 for suggesting Emacs client, which uses usually Unix domain sockets, for a remote communication problem. -1 for blethering about Emacs without using it.