# How to use SSH and SUDO together with TRAMP in Emacs

Tags: emacs, ssh, sudo, tramp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs)

I want to open a file using sudo (say, /etc/hosts) on a remote machine connected by ssh using TRAMP on Emacs.

I tried couple of options, but none of them worked. Can anybody tell me how to go about it?

Thank you

Comment: Duplicate of: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs">Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs</a> See documentation here:
http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Multi_002dhops

Comment: But [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4725727/200567) answer actually works.

Comment: Try this: [`C-x C-f /ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:remotehost:/path/to/file RET`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc18)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

In recent Emacsen and Unixes it's dead simple, just visit a file (`C-x C-f`) and start the file name with `ssh://server:/file`.

If you are using Windows, first install Putty and put it in your PATH environment variable.  Then when you visit a file use `plink://server:/file` instead of `ssh://server:/file`.

**EDIT:**

This answer is wrong, see the answer below.

Comment: Would that not require him to authenticate as root?

Comment: ssh will by default use your current username.  You can another one  by using `ssh://username:password@server:/file` Entering the password every time gets tedious really fast though, so I suggest setting up public-key authentication (then it's just `ssh://username@server:/file`).

Comment: That gives access to the file as 'username', but the question is now how to save that file if it is owned by root on the remote machine. In Ubuntu installations, for example, it is not possible (by default) to login as root, so you have to access the file as 'username' and then save it as root.

Answer (score 40):

Use following in your .emacs

```
(set-default 'tramp-default-proxies-alist (quote ((".*" "\\`root\\'" "/ssh:%h:"))))
```

Then you can simply type:

```
C-x C-f /sudo:root@host[#port]:/path/to/file
```

It will ask you for your password  to access remote shell and then your password again for **sudo** access.

Comment: Does this login to the remote server as root?

Comment: This will login you as a user and run sudo after it. No need to allow ssh for root ;)

Comment: I've tried your suggestion and another one (in the duplicate thread mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs) but neither of them are working.

Comment: It seems you have wrong version of tramp. Use this solution: http://serverfault.com/questions/123802/emacs-tramp-sudo-to-root-on-localhost-hangs-after-asking-for-password/223371#223371

Comment: Thanks. I installed tramp 2.1.19 and inserted my remote username before the "%h" and I am now able to login to the machine (not as root) and save files as root.

Comment: If you are doing other manipulation of your `tramp-default-proxies-alist` you might want to use `add-to-list` instead of `set-default`.