# emacs24: ftp doesn't work

Tags: emacs, emacs24

this is a real problem to me:

Using emacs23 you connect to ftp with command:

```
/ftp:user@domain.ltd@ftp.domain.ltd/
```

So it ask you the password and you enjoy programming online...

well...this in emacs 23 ... **but** now i have to work with emacs24 using its new features and that command don't work anymore...

i'm desperate! help me...this happened in all pc's and brand new system (ubuntu, trisquel, windows, mac..) i'm using so i think its a problem of emacs24 but i don't know how to solve it...

thanks in advance

Comment: I don't use tramp over ftp, but is `@domain.ltd@ftp.domain.ltd` actually correct? What does that do? (If it's an Ange-FTP specific multi-hop syntax, maybe check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16408592/324105 )

Comment: No, it should be just /ftp:user@ftp.domain.ltd/.

Comment: i haven't ssh on servers i use...i need using ftp and tramp don't work with ftp. i'm trying using ange-ftp as i always done...emacs23 works, emacs24 don't with that text.What can i do?

Comment: Given that you haven't updated the question and you've failed to clarify, I still have absolutely no idea whether you are attempting to use `/ftp:user@domain.ltd@ftp.domain.ltd/` or if you're actually using `/ftp:user@ftp.domain.ltd/`.

Comment: ACTUALLY USING: /ftp:user@domain.ltd@ftp.domain.ltd/ just because my username is user@domain.ltd...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved in this mode.

download emacs-24.1xxxxxx.tar.gz from here

http://alpha.gnu.org/gnu/emacs/pretest/

sudo apt-get install xorg-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libgif-dev libtiff-dev libncurses-dev

tar xvf emacs-24.1xxxxxxx.tar.gz

cd /emacs-24.1xxxxxxx

./configure

make

----------- I'VE TESTING THE FUNCTIONALITY OF FTP in /SRC/emacs >>**>FTP WORKS!!!!** 
----THEN-----

sudo make install

emacs

Comment: So which version of Emacs 24 *were* you using? The current stable 24.3 release is either identical to the most recent pretest build, or else slightly newer. Building from a stable release seems a better idea in general.