# Opening a remote (SSH) file with sudo (tramp) in Emacs is failing

Tags: emacs, ssh, sudo, tramp

I have followed (and partially adapted) the recommendations in [Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs)

My custom.el contains something like the following:

```
(custom-set-variables
  '(tramp-default-proxies-alist (quote (("my-sudo-alias" nil "/ssh:user@host")))))
```

However when I try to visit a remote file say `sudo:my-sudo-alias:/etc/whatever` I get the following error: Method `scpc' is not supported for multi-hops.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something else in your proxy list is interfering?

What does `C-h v tramp-default-proxies-alist` look like?

You might also have `scpc` set as your `tramp-default-method`. I don't *think* that should be an issue in this case, but I'm not certain of that.

Did you try the ad-hoc approach that I [detailed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs/16408592#16408592) in the Q&A you linked to?

If that doesn't work, try emptying the proxy list, and then trying it again.

Note also that the `scpc` & `rsyncc` tramp methods are deprecated in the latest Tramp (ControlMaster is now used automatically if it is available).

Comment: Hum... I need to load tramp before I can do C-h v tramp-default-proxies-alist. Maybe this is Ok. But the value is simply: `Its value is (("sqli" nil "/ssh:USER-HERE@HOST"))`...

Comment: C-h i g Only completes "(tramp)". There is a multi-hop chapter (4.9) but I don't see any "Ad-hop multi-hop" chapter...

Comment: Yeah, you can't auto-complete across manuals, which is a shame. You *can* within the manual though. e.g.: `C-h i g (tramp) RET m Ad-hocTAB`. I did think this was added in Emacs 24.1, but the NEWS file suggests it was 24.3, so you probably just need to upgrade.

Comment: Well, you should be able to get a working proxy without upgrading, but upgrading is probably a good idea in general. Certainly if you're running an earlier version of Emacs 24. If you're still on Emacs 23 then it might be more effort, but it's something you'll most likely want to do at some point.

Comment: I've just tried the C-x C-f /ssh:you@remotehost|sudo:them@remotehost:/path/to/file RET as described in [the link provided](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs/16408592#16408592). So I will accept this answer and thank @phils.