# How sudo edit local file with Emacs on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

After read [Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs) then I can sudo edit remote file via 

`/ssh:username@hostname|sudo:username@hostname:/the-file`

but I can't sudo edit local file, Emacs's tramp prompts the password of `root@hostname`, because on Ubuntu there no root's password exists (see [RootSudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo)) .

So there is a way to sudo edit local file on Ubuntu?

Summary:
If you want to edit remote/local file with Emacs, @[phils](https://stackoverflow.com/users/324105/phils) has a good answer at 
[Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs);
If you used projectile (version<=0.12.0) and can not sudo edit local file(such as `Tamp: sending password` or hang) you can try the following code that fix my issue:

```
  (when (package-installed-p 'projectile)
  (defun projectile-project-root ()
    "Retrieves the root directory of a project if available.
    The current directory is assumed to be the project's root otherwise."
    (let ((dir default-directory))
      (or (--reduce-from
           (or acc
               (let* ((cache-key (format "%s-%s" it dir))
                      (cache-value (gethash cache-key projectile-project-root-cache)))
                 (if cache-value
                     (if (eq cache-value 'no-project-root)
                         nil
                       cache-value)
                   (let ((value (funcall it (file-truename dir))))
                     (puthash cache-key (or value 'no-project-root) projectile-project-root-cache)
                     value))))
           nil
           projectile-project-root-files-functions)
          (if projectile-require-project-root
              (error "You're not in a project")
            default-directory))))
  (projectile-global-mode))
```

To see [Simple tramp with sudo hangs on 'Sending password'](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/issues/594) and [projectile-global-mode prevents new processes from working over TRAMP #523](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/523) for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run sudo commands under Ubuntu, you must use your *own* password instead of the (non-existing) root password.

Comment: The question is how to sudo edit file in Emacs on Ubuntu, and there're no effect after I input my own password when Emacs' tramp prompts ```sudo: root@hostname```. That's the problem.

Comment: I always use `/sudo::/path/to/file` to edit under Ubuntu, no problem. Maybe you (you as Ubuntu user) don't have sufficient rights to run sudo? What happens if you run in a shell `sudo id` ?

Comment: I'd sufficient rights to run sudo, sudo run in Terminal is OK. The Emacs mini buffer prompts: ```Password for /sudo:root@hostname```. 
The output of ```sudo id```:

```uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)```

Comment: Apply `(setq tramp-verbose 10)` prior opening `/sudo::`. Then there will be a Tramp debug buffer, which you might show.

Comment: Hang on ```Tramp: Sending Password```

Comment: *tramp...* buffer says:
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
Sorry, try again.
sudo: 3 incorrect password attempts

Comment: Like this issure on github [Simple tramp with sudo hangs on 'Sending passwo](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude/issues/594)

Comment: Do you use projectile? I've just seen another discussion where projectile has confused Tramp. Have you tried starting `emacs -Q` and then open `/sudo::` ?

Comment: I used projectile, the issue is abused file-truename in projectile-project-root function in projectile.el at version 0.12.0 . 
There has a fix at [Fix #657](https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/commit/4e3cc0ae40256478198a46d27d9efe41b47f7ca2) at version 0.13.0 . My projectile is 0.12.0, so extract projectile-project-root function definition into my emacs's loading files can fix it.

Comment: I'll append the fix to the question let someone know how to fix it when they meet the same issue. I found the question had been flag as 'not useful' if you do not think so, please help me mark it up, thank you and thank you let me get the right way to find the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Simply skip the `user@system` part altogether:

```
C-x C-f /sudo::/path/to/file RET
```

Answer (score 1):

I open the file that I want to edit (as a normal file) and then do the M-x sudo-edit using the code (option A) from this blog post:

http://emacsredux.com/blog/2013/04/21/edit-files-as-root/

Pasting the code here, just in case the post goes away in the future.

```
 (defun sudo-edit (&optional arg)
  "Edit currently visited file as root.

With a prefix ARG prompt for a file to visit.
Will also prompt for a file to visit if current
buffer is not visiting a file."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (or arg (not buffer-file-name))
      (find-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:"
                         (ido-read-file-name "Find file(as root): ")))
    (find-alternate-file (concat "/sudo:root@localhost:" buffer-file-name))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
ssh username@hostname
sudo emacs /the-file
```

I cannot think of a way to do that in one line. You first need to connect on the remote host via ssh, your regular password and then sudo edit the file. Depending on the guest OS it will prompt you for the appropriate password for sudo.

Comment: Sorry about the question confusing, how to sudo edit local file in Emacs on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -2):

To edit with `emacs` as root some local (on your own computer) file `/some/path/local.txt` just run

```
  sudo emacs /some/path/local.txt
```

Once `emacs` has started, you cannot make it write a file with root ownership (unless it is group or world writable, which is generally a bad thing).

If you have an `sshd` daemon correctly configured, you could `ssh root@localhost` (perhaps via [Emacs Tramp](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) ...) and use emacs Tramp etc... I don't recommend that. On Ubuntu, you'll need to create the `root` user (or create a `myroot` user with uid 0 and use `myroot@localhost`).

You could also edit (as an ordinary user) some file in `/tmp/` like `/tmp/foobar` and copy it as root later: `sudo cp -v /tmp/foobar /some/path/for/root/foobar`

Emacs Tramp has some `sudo` and `su` [specific syntax](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode#toc16); perhaps you want that...

Comment: It's the another way, but I just want to start Emacs normally and can sudo edit local file all in Emacs.

Comment: As I explained, this is not generally possible.

Comment: Sudo edit remote file in Emacs is OK, It's possible if treat sudo edit local file as the remote file via ssh?

Comment: Basile Starynkevitch: Presumably you are unfamiliar with Emacs, but had you followed the link in the question you would have noticed that this is entirely possible via the Tramp facility mentioned in this question.

Comment: And Tramp is based above `ssh` IIRC

Comment: ...and the Tramp `sudo:` method doesn't work for you? (I'm genuinely curious). The `su:` and `sudo:` methods do not use ssh (although in the *remote* host case for this question, obviously ssh is required).

Comment: I don't like Tramp and never use it for root access. I much prefer `sudo emacs`  and I often use a specific color for root emacs: `sudo emacs -bg lightyellow` (and quite often I use `vi` for sysadmin editions, and `emacs` for daily developer work)

Comment: @phils: you are right. The cause is projectile (version 0.12.0) conflicts with tramp and I appended a fix to the question to let someone know. If you don't think the question does not show research efforts or something else, please mark it up. Finally, thank you for your answer and for your comments.