# How do I log history in a tramp emacs ssh session

Tags: bash, emacs, ssh, tramp

I started using tramp with emacs as per the discussion here ([Open file via SSH and Sudo with Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs)) in order to use my emacs configs without having to install them on the server/user I was sshing to. Apparently the default setting of this sets HISTFILE=/dev/null, and I got a concerned email from my company's infosec team asking why I was doing this. Is there a way to turn this setting off and log history the normal way? Would like to keep using this tool in compliance with security rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting HISTFILE=/dev/null is disabled in development version of Tramp, because there is a bug in bash which corrupts /dev/null then. Likely, the security department of your company is concerned about this.

If you have a recent Tramp (say the one bundled with Emacs 24.5), setting HISTFILE=/dev/null is hardwired in tramp-sh.el. You would need to patch it there.

If you install a newer Tramp version like 2.2.12 (see the Tramp manual how to do this), you could use the variable `tramp-histfile-override` to set your own value. Per default it is set to ".tramp_history", but there are also other possibilities. See the docstring of that variable.

Comment: Thank you!  I set it to nil to stop leaving `.tramp_history` files all over our servers... Most likely infosec are concerned that overriding HISTFILE to /dev/null means that you're no longer logging shell commands, and so they will be unable to guarantee to your clients' auditors that all shell activity is logged and can be traced to a person.