# Edit file as other user on other host in Emacs

Tags: ssh, emacs, su, tramp

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs) but my situation is slightly different. Currently I edit the file like this:

1. ssh HOST_1
2. ssh HOST_2
3. su OTHER_USER
4. vim ~/FILENAME

How do I tell Emacs (using tramp) to edit this file, while including the hop from `HOST_1` to `HOST_2` as well as the `su OTHER_USER`?

"multi-hop" with "me" as the user works fine:

```
/sshx:HOST_1|sshx:HOST_2:/user/me/FILENAME
```

However, adding `sudo su OTHER_USER` fails:

```
/sshx:HOST_1|sshx:HOST_2|sudo:OTHER_USER@HOST_2:
```

After typing the final colon, I am prompted for a password. After entering the password, I can type the remote file path, but it appears to be an empty filesystem somewhere, with no folders or files at all.

The `*Messages*` buffer contains this:

```
Tramp: Encoding local file ‘/tmp/tramp.61Eexc.ulUhgA’ using ‘base64-encode-region’...done
Tramp: Decoding remote file ‘/ssh:HOST_2:/tmp/tramp.ulUhgA’ using ‘base64 -d -i >%s’...done
```

I've replicated this on my preferred Emacs setup (using `sshx` with spacemacs 0.200.13, Emacs 26.3) as well as a completely vanilla Emacs 25.2.2 (using `ssh`).

Comment: Per the Q&A you linked to, that would typically be `/ssh:HOST_1|ssh:HOST_2|su:OTHER_USER@HOST_2:`.  It's not obvious why you've indicated the `sshx` method here, unless you're using Windows?  Nothing else in the question suggests that, though.  I suspect you could use either `su:` or `sudo:`, but certainly try the other one if the first doesn't work for you.

Comment: Start `emacs -Q` and try Tramp's multi-hop syntax. If it works, check your init files, which loaded package breaks this.

Comment: I can multi-hop (with my normal emacs config as well as `emacs -Q`) but when I multi-hop AND `sudo:otheruser@remote` it prompts for password and then seems to break. No file completion, no files at all.

Comment: @phils the error message is there, but when I first started this question I hadn't waited long enough - after typing the 3rd colon, I can in fact access HOST_2's filesystem. Still having errors when trying to `sudo su OTHER_USER` though. I've edited the question to be more clear.

Comment: I guess you want to set `tramp-verbose` to a higher value and then check the debug buffer, which will probably be named something like: `*debug tramp/sudo root@HOST_2*`.  @MichaelAlbinus can advise better on the specifics -- I'm unsure how much verbosity would be appropriate here.

Comment: Setting `tramp-verbose` to 6 shall be sufficient.