# Plink + sudo in emacs: connection without password

Tags: ssh, emacs, sudo, plink, tramp

I would like to modify a file on a remote server with emacs on a user I can only access through `sudo su - username` without a password.

I am currently able to modify files on my personal space on this server using:

```
C-x C-f /plink:me@server:/path/file
```

I read [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177687/open-file-via-ssh-and-sudo-with-emacs) that I could use the following to open a file as the other user:

```
C-x C-f /plink:me@server|sudo:other@server:/path/file
```

The problem is that using this syntax, emacs asks me for a password `Password for /sudo:other@server:` which I don't have.. giving an empty password does not work, neither does giving my user's password.

Is there a way to configure tramp to connect to this other user as `sudo su - other` would do without asking for a password?

PS: I am using emacs 28.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify a new Tramp method, derived from the `sudo` method:

```
(add-to-list 'tramp-methods
             `("mysudo"
               (tramp-login-program        "sudo")
               (tramp-login-args           (("su") ("-" "%u")))
               (tramp-remote-shell         ,tramp-default-remote-shell)
               (tramp-remote-shell-login   ("-l"))
               (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
               (tramp-connection-timeout   10)
               (tramp-session-timeout      300)))
```

Then you can open a remote file like

```
C-x C-f /plink:me@server|mysudo:other@server:/path/file
```

Disclaimer: it is untested.

Comment: Thanks! I just had to add `(require 'tramp)` before this in my .emacs for it to work but it worked as expected :)